# How to get the proper output?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, shell, text-editing

I am working with an algorithm that produces outputs like these:

```
...
2
3
0
 & :instance & :|V| & :|A| & :T & :model & :rootLP & :maxFlowCuts & :maxFlowCutsTime & :lazyCuts & :cost & :solverTime & :relativeGAP & :nodeCount & :meters & :tourMinutes & :blocksMeters
 & alto-santo-3000-2016 & 1458 & 2124306 & 120.0 & SBRPMaxComplete & 289.0 & 101 & 1728.987965326 & 5 & 289.0 & 227.84233403205872 & 0.0 & 0 & 49984.0 & 90.6765 & 3489.0
########################################################
Application parameters:
  batch  =>  nothing
  instance  =>  "data/instances-dengue-ARP/real_instances/complete/alto-santo-confirmed/alto-santo-3000-2017.txt"
  nosolve  =>  false
  out  =>  "solutions/alto-santo-3000-2017-confirmed"
  instance-type  =>  "carlos"
  vehicle-time-limit  =>  "120"
...
```

And I want to get only these pieces of the output:

```
 & :instance & :|V| & :|A| & :T & :model & :rootLP & :maxFlowCuts & :maxFlowCutsTime & :lazyCuts & :cost & :solverTime & :relativeGAP & :nodeCount & :meters & :tourMinutes & :blocksMeters
 & alto-santo-3000-2016 & 1458 & 2124306 & 120.0 & SBRPMaxComplete & 289.0 & 101 & 1728.987965326 & 5 & 289.0 & 227.84233403205872 & 0.0 & 0 & 49984.0 & 90.6765 & 3489.0
```

Basically, I want to get only all the pieces that contain these 17 columns. I would like to know if someone knows any program or terminal command to get only the desired part from the output.

Thank you and best regards.

UPDATE 1: My operational system is the Linux Ubuntu 18.04.
UPDATE 2: The desired piece may be located in any range of lines of the file.

Comment: Your title is very vague, can you make the question title more specific so that future SU users have a better experience, please?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @spikey_richie sorry, that was the best way I found to express my problem, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @harrymc Linux, Ubuntu.

Comment: e.g. `producer_software | tail -n first_line | head -n line_count` - if it always is on specific line(s) of the output...  which the above does not tell currently.

Comment: Thanks. Check the update 2.

Answer (score 0):

I found out after checking the `grep` documentation.

```
grep -A1 ':instance' output_file
```

Everyone, thanks for the support.